# background color over background color

Tags: css

I want to give the element a background color with border radius and an additional background color to show where the border radius removed the first one.

Who knows how?

Pseudo-code:

```
.the-element-class {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color-with-border-radius: $color-light-blue;
  background-color-without-border-radius: $color-light-red;
}
```

Comment: bg-color  + radial-gradient .....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a overlay using `::before` selector to achieve the requirement, please check the below example!

```css
.special {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.special::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="special"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use radial-gradient:

```css
.box {
  background: 
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,yellow 98%,transparent 100%),
    red;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

You can also have a different coloration for each corner:

```css
.box {
  background: 
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,yellow 98%,transparent 100%),
    linear-gradient(red,red)       top left    /51% 51%,
    linear-gradient(blue,blue)     top right   /51% 51%,
    linear-gradient(green,green)   bottom left /51% 51%,
    linear-gradient(purple,purple) bottom right/51% 51%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```